# Authentication troubles for google cloud speech api

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I trying to get started with google cloud speech with node.js but I am having troubles with authentication. I am following the setup steps outlined on the [github](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech/tree/master). I tried the setup in this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries) but had no luck.I keep getting this error..

```
ERROR: Error: Unexpected error while acquiring application default credentials: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

I am looking for some insight on how to setup the credentials so I can start running the models. 
Any input would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message said, you should read [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials) to get your credentials set up.

Comment: Thanks for the help, after reviewing those docs I realized that I had set the environment variable wrong.

Comment: @Jacob Great! If this answer helped you, please upvote it as well.